# Configure rails console depending on environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-console

Is it possible to configure rails application to make rails console behave different in different environment? For example: on production i would like rails console to have one set of colours, but on localhost (development mode) a completely different one. Is it even possible, or maybe rails console cannot be configured from application level?

Answer (score 2):

Include in Gemfile:

```
gem 'some_formatting_gem_name', :group => :development
```

While starting, mention environment as well.

```
RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rails console
```

Or:

```
bundle exec rails console development
```

Comment: nice but i need it to be done WITHOUT mentioning the environment while starting console. thats kinda the point, to be able to differ environments

Comment: Have an environment set system wide. In your bash profile or bashrc include `export RAILS_ENV=environment_name`.

Answer (score 0):

you can open your console in different environments (if that what you were asking for)

Simply use:

```
rails c [environment]
```

Eg.

```
rails c development
```